# using flush and clear after each persist or merge

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Well, i have a trigger function in postgreSQL that generate a number each time a new row is inserted. But JPA/Hibernate don't show this generated number, after a "entityManager.persist(bean)". So i did the following to force it:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public AbstractBean save(AbstractBean bean) {
        try {
            logger.info("Salvando Bean " + bean.getClass().getName());
            entityManager.persist(bean);
            entityManager.flush();
            entityManager.clear();
            return bean;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar salvar. MSG ORIGINAL: "
                    + e.getMessage());
            throw new DAOException("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar salvar");
        }
    }
```

I inserted the "flush and clear" after persist method and everything is fine. But my big doubt is: My method "save" is called for all application to save any JavaBean, so if i make flush and clear in all persist or merge don't have problem ? This is the better choice ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is not optimal to have `flush` and `clear` for all `saves` - what is the purpose of a cache in this situation.

I would implement

```
em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evict(theSpecialClass, thePrimaryKey);
```

for where `bean instanceOf theSpecialClass`

Comment: evict is the better solution but i'm using JPA (entityManager) and i don't have this tool, just clear().

Comment: em is the entityManager, anyway, my main point it to test to see if the bean you are saving is `instanceOf` this special bean

Comment: My entityManager (em) object don't have getEntityManagerFactory() method.

Comment: I also recommend that you upgrade from Java 5.

Comment: In that case what is wrong with http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getEntityManagerFactory()

Comment: BEcause i'm using this object type: protected javax.persistence.EntityManager entityManager;

Comment: I really don't have "getEntityManagerFactory" method in my object EntityManager

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43955/discussion-between-user2776409-and-user2310289)

Comment: I don't know why you don't have this method either, but not such a big deal if you can get your code to work. But I suggest that if your bean that you want this special flushing to work for is called myBean, then

`if (bean instanceOf myBean) { 
entityManager.flush(); 
entityManager.clear(); 
}`

Comment: Thanks. I will make my flush and clear in BO (Bussiness Object) and not in DAO, as i proposed. In this way i can grantee that just when a specific is trigger i will flush and clear everything.